# Browser update constantly changing image

Tags: java, php, image

Im having a tricky predicament getting an updated image to show on my website.

**Whats Happening**

I have a java program which is taking a screenshot of my screen and using FTP to upload it to my web server

every time it uploads it overwrites the previous image stored on the server with the same name

Basically I just pull the most updated image from the server and display it on my webpage

**Where im stuck**

Im stuck because at the end of my image it looks like this 
`<img src="screenshot-x1we45k.jpg?02:10:54"`

ive attached a random string to the end of my images name to force the browser to look for the new image and load it AND i've also double checked that the image on my webserver is the most recent image that was uploaded so i know it's not a problem with my java program because everything is transferred to the server correctly its just not displaying right..... anything i could try!?

Comment: If you reload the page does it show your new image, or are you trying to do this without reloading the page?

Comment: create unique image name on run time

Comment: i am reloading the page asynchronously using jquery's load() function  and it loads a php script which queries my database for the most up to date link to the image

Comment: if i created a unique name every time i uploaded a screenshot to the server it would upload thousands of images in just an hour or so